# Facing issue generating access token using refresh token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token, passport-google-oauth2

Im getting the below error when i generated the refresh token and tried to generate new access token.
The refresh token is newly generated. It is not expired. I need to implement the regeneration of access token functionlity. Unfortunately facing this issue.
{ error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request' }

I tried changing the paths from http://localhost:3001 to http://127.0.0.1:3001, and check the system time match and all other conditions but it dint work

Comment: please edit your question and include your code